# Enclose columns containing alphabets with single quotes using awk

Tags: unix, awk

Can awk process this?

Input

```
Neil,23,01-Jan-1990
25,Reena,19900203
```

Output

```
'Neil',23,'01-Jan-1990'
25,'Reena',19900203
```

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect was my first attempt

```
sed -r 's/([^,]*[a-zA-Z]+[^,]*)(,{0,1})/"\1"\2/g' inputfile
```

@Sundeep gave an excellent comment: I need single quotes and it can be shorter:
I tried to match including the `,` of end-of-line, causing some complexity for matching. You can just match between the seperators making sure there is an alphabetic character somewhere.

```
sed 's/[^,]*[a-zA-Z][^,]*/\x27&\x27/g' inputfile
```

Comment: OP wants single quotes, not double... and this can be simplified to `sed 's/[^,]*[a-zA-Z][^,]*/\x27&\x27/g'`

Comment: Is `\x27` for single quotes robust in all seds? It's not in awk at least due to it relying on undefined behavior, see http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote, but `\047` doesn't seem to work at all in sed as `\0` is interpreted the same as `&` so I've always relied on `'\''` for a single quote in sed for that reason.

Comment: @EdMorton at least for `gnu sed` it is robust... https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Escapes the syntax is `\xxx Produces or matches a character whose hexadecimal ASCII value is xx` and for octal need to use `\o047`

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** approach:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/[[:alpha:]]/) $i="\047"$i"\047"}1' OFS="," file
```

The output:

```
'Neil',23,'01-Jan-1990'
25,'Reena',19900203
```

---

- `if($i~/[[:alpha:]]/)` - if field contains alphabetic character
- `\047` - octal code of single quote `'` character

Answer (score 0):

You might use this script:

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN { OFS=FS="," }

{ for(i= 1; i<=NF; i++) { 
    if( !match( $i, /^[0-9]+$/ ) ) $i = "'" $i "'"
  }
  print
}
```

and run it like this: `awk -f script.awk yourfile` .

**Explanation**

- the first line sets up the input and output Fieldseparators to `,`.
- the loop tests each field, whether it contains only digits (`/^[0-9]+$/`):
  if not the field is put in quotes